# How do I deal with Connection refused error in rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

This is my code:

```
pkgs <- c("rvest", "urltools")
sapply(pkgs, library, character.only = T)
name <- 'cry'
url1 = URLencode(paste0('https://www.google.co.za/search?q=',name))
htmlpage <- html_session(url1)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to www.google.co.za port 443: Connection refused`

What can I do about the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Port 443 Timed Out - Scraping Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202601/error-port-443-timed-out-scraping-data)

Comment: Any proxy settings?

Comment: Not sure. How do I find them? And what do I do when I find them?